# Scheduled tasks invalid filter using XML

Tags: scheduled-tasks, xml

I try to make a trigger using XML on the Window's task scheduler, but the tool tells me a filter is invalid and i was unable to find what is wrong.

My current XML is

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">
      *[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and (Level=4 or Level=0) and Task = 12801 and (EventID=4656) ]] and
      *[EventData[Data[@Name='SubjectUserSid' and (Data='S-1-5-18')]] and
       [Data[@Name='ObjectType' and (Data=Key) ]]]

   </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

When I remove

```
and
           [Data[@Name='ObjectType' and (Data=Key) ]]
```

The XML is accepted without error. As I don't understand what is wrong on my last line I'm stuck.

Comment: I don't know if it belongs here or on StackOverflow as it's one the edge of both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some missing closing square brackets around the SubjectUserSid and ObjectType attributes, the "*[EventData" missing from the last query line, and missing quotes around the Data value "Key". This works in my EventViewer:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">
      *[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and (Level=4 or Level=0) and Task = 12801 and (EventID=4656) ]] and
      *[EventData[Data[@Name='SubjectUserSid'] and (Data='S-1-5-18') ]] and
      *[EventData[Data[@Name='ObjectType'] and (Data='Key') ]]
   </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Comment: Will definitively test it, errors you reported seems logic, thanks you!